Aspect Ratio Cutting Off Map in Matplotlib
I have code that plots a map with user specified lat/long bounds. I use a defined map aspect ratio in order to keep the map at a constant size. If I don't my figtext moved well out of position. However, trying with some test cases where the Y-lim is larger than the X-lim Matplotlib cuts off the ylim not showing the entire map to preserve aspect ratio. How do I force it to show the map but still have my figtext.
I've tried setting the axes to scaled which creates the same issues as a non-set aspect ratio. I've tried setting to equal aspect which still cuts off data. I'm looking to force the map to show more of one coordinate to ensure the full bounds of another is shown.

A [mre] would be welcome. Maybe it's just me (not a native speaker) but I do not understand your question.

I'd like to point out that in a geographic projection the aspect ratio is inherently fixed, and this is the main reason I do not understand your Q.
